# How to recreate a dynamic array by removing some characters and make it another array value in java script?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let us suppose I have a dynamic array in Javascript like:

```
      example = ["one", "two", "three", "four<br" , "five"]
```

And I want to make it:

```
      example2 = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "<br", "five"]
```

Can anyone help me please? Remember it is a dynamic array, so we wont know the exact place where

```
   "<br"
```

is located within the array.

Comment: The second one doesn’t even make sense. Do you really want to make `twothree` into one single value? Suppose not. Use your _words_ to describe what you actually want to achieve here.

Comment: What makes the array dynamic? It looks like an ordinary array of strings to me. Just loop over the array, and if it contains `<br` you remove the part before that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Please no-one answer until the OP adds their own efforts)

Comment: What is `"twho" . "three"` in the result? Javascript doesn't allow a `.` between array elements. And you have nothing separating `"three"` and `"four"`, that's also invalid.

Comment: Sorry for the typos, I am new to this!

Answer (score 2):

You could split the strings with a positive lookahead of `<`, then concat the parts to the result array.

```js
var example = ["one", "two", "three", "four<br" , "five"],
    result = example.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.split(/(?=<)/));
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why use `reduce` instead of `map`? Then you don't need `concat`.

Comment: you need to return two values, `'four'` **and** `'<br'`. with mapping you miss one item.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see that he was splitting up that element, I thought he was just removing the prefix.

Comment: I am looking for another way, because I may have many "<br" so, if I split, there will be lots more to concat. But I do appreciate your help and time.

Comment: @Sunny, maybe you add another example for highlighting the problem better.

Comment: I do believe that you understood the problem and your previous answer does, what I am trying to achieve. It is just not practical if I have lots of "<br" to concat to reach the final array.  if I write all the codes, it will be very big.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to understand logic of splitting and incrementing the array, you can use the below function to understand:

```js
var example = ["one", "two", "three", "four<br" , "five"];
  var substring = "<br";
  var stringFound = false;
  var incrementIndex;
  var index, firstPart, secondPart;



  for (var i = 0; i<example.length; i++) 
    //find where the "<br" is in your array

    if(example[i].indexOf(substring) !== -1) {
      stringFound = true;
      incrementIndex = i;
      //if found split the string
      index = example[i].indexOf("<");// Gets the first index where a < occours
      firstPart = example[i].substr(0, index);// Gets the first part
      secondPart = example[i].substr(index);// Gets the second part
    }
    
   if(stringFound === true){ 
  
    for(var j= example.length ; j > incrementIndex + 1; j--) {
     example[j] = example[j-1];
    }
    example[incrementIndex] = firstPart;
    example[incrementIndex + 1] = secondPart;
  }
  console.log(example);
```